# Crawlers other than Nutch that work with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to get some suggestions as I setup my data system. I'd like to setup a system for web crawling. It'll crawl probably a few hundred/thousand sites on a regular basis.

I'm aware of Nutch and have used Nutch, however I'd like to know if others know of a better crawler than Nutch.

I'm also using Elasticsearch as the indexer and its quite hard to get Nutch to work with newer versions of ES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler) is based on Apache Storm and is not only a full-featured crawler but also has a focus on Near Real Time crawling. ES is usually very updated, at the moment of this writing, supports ES v6.1.1 (https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/pom.xml#L20) so this could work you. Keep in mind that is a different approach & technologie than Nutch, although it uses some of the ideas behind Apache Nutch.

Also, in https://github.com/BruceDone/awesome-crawler you can find a list of a lot of crawlers written in a lot of different languages.